# How to render content from a sidebar menu into main content area?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a user profile page with a sidebar menu with links which I would like to render/display into the main content area upon clicking any one of the links without the whole page re-rendering. Any ideas as to the best way to go about doing this task?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a front-end framework like AngularJS or Ember. If it is static data or very simple, you could use the tabs functionality built into jQuery: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: thanks @Nitsew for your comment...certainly has some ideas now.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a basic iron-router question. If you follow the [iron router tutorial](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) you'll see how to render a route into a template. On the links in your sidebar/nav you would use `{{pathFor 'myPath'}}` and that would automatically pump the `myPath` template into the `{{> yield}}` of your layout without re-rendering. With iron-router and Meteor you basically never re-render.

An alternative is to just render all the divs in your layout and hide/show them based on nav item clicks. You can even do that without javascript using bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks Michel for your comments.